# How would I detect clicks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, user-input

I'm building a little web game in node.js, and I've been using event listeners for input, and it's worked fine for things like key presses and mouse movement.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseInput);
```

*(all of these have worked perfectly)*

But when I tried using the `mouseup`/`mousedown` events (and also `pointerup`/`pointerdown`), they won't register. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Does it have to click on something?

```
window.addEventListener("pointerdown", changeShooting(true));
window.addEventListener("pointerup", changeShooting(false));
```

*(doesn't work)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function to `addEventListener`, while you are passing the **result** of the call to `changeShooting` (which I assume does not return a function).

In order to do that, you can define an inline function like:

```js
window.addEventListener("pointerdown", function() {
  changeShooting(true)
});
```

If you need to remove the listener later, you have to define it explicitly:

```js
function onPointerDown() {
  changeShooting(true);
}

window.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);

// later somewhere
window.removeEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
```